# How to show JSON HttpResponse after HttpEvent progress?

Tags: angular, httpresponse

Following the tutorial here [Listening to Progress Events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events)

I want to ask if it is possible to return the `response` from the server after the `HttpEvent` progress?

Here is my sample code.

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, {
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'json',
});

getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      return 'Uploading data...'

    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total)
      return `is ${percentDone} uploaded.`

    case HttpEventType.Response:
       return `was completely uploaded. ` + event.body; // I want to show the json response from server.
      //return HttpEventType.Response;

    default:
      // code...
      return `surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
  }
}

this.http.request(req).pipe(
  map(event => console.log(this.getEventMessage(event))),
  tap(message => console.log('Message: '+ message)), // message undefined
  last(),
).subscribe(response => {
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', response); // It returns undefined
})
```

I want to show the `json` response from server. Seriously I don't have any idea on how to do it. any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: currently what are you getting?

Comment: it always undefined.

Comment: OK so I didn't realize that the result will be found in `case HttpEventType.Response`. so to get the response from the `server` just simply `return event.body` and don't include anything to it. That's it. Sorry because I am focusing on the response from `subscribe`.